# .Net Core IFormFile not working in Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a file that I'm submitting using ajax, but in the server I'm not receiving anything.

```
let file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
```

I don't do a ajax call.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/File/Create', file)
```

In my .Net Core I'm expecting this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] IFormFile file)
    {

        return Ok();
    }
```

This is not working. I'm wordering in my data type is wrong.

Comment: Please show the sent data and what `file` contains on the server. Also, what does `axios` do if not an `AJAX` post?

Comment: See the [example](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html) for how to upload files using axios. As a minimum, you need to work with `FormData`.

Comment: You’re doing it wrong on the client side. Take a look [at this axios example on how to upload files](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your problem is described briefly but assuming everything else has been configured properly on your client and service,

I believe your main problem here is that your sent data missing `key: 'file'` which results in `file` being received as `null`. So, this must work:

```
axios.post
(
  'http://localhost:5000/File/Create',
  {
    file: file
  }
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `axios` handle the upload. But generally you need to send the FormData which has the file. When using jQuery ajax to send this form data, you need to make sure that you set the `processData` and `contentType` flags to `false`

Something like this would work

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fdata = new FormData();

    var fileInput = $('#logo')[0];
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    fdata.append("logo", file);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "@Url.Action("Create", "File")",
        data: fdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(result) {
        // do something with the result now
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

Assuming you have a Create action method in FileController which takes the file and save it to your some directory in your app root.

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
    public FileController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveFile(IFormFile logo)
    {
        if (logo != null)
        {
            //simply saving to "uploads" directory
            var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, logo.FileName);
            logo.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));  
            return Json(new { status = "success" });              
        }
        return Json(new { status = "error" });
    }
}
```